# What is the optimal tiling of a regular n-gon in the plane?

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, tessellations

I want to tile the plane with equal-sized regular polygons of $n$ sides.

Obviously for some $n$, the tiles will be able to tessellate and cover the whole plane (e.g triangles, squares, hexagons)

I just want to know the maximum percentage of the plane that can be covered for each $n$.

What happens when $n$ approaches infinity? I know the shape will tend to a circle, which has a known optimal packing, but is there a general pattern to it?

Comment: A cursory Google search for "regular polygon packing" turned up "[Dense Periodic Packings of Regular Polygons](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00247157/document)" by Y. Limon Duparcmeur et al. (1995), which seems relevant.

Comment: ... and [Euclidean Tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_polytopes_and_compounds#Euclidean_tilings)